# Decode / encode html escaped special characters in Python

Tags: python, html, encoding

I have some text that has html escape codes in it that I am struggling to fully decode / encode to display properly with Python (ultimately in a Django application).

`"&quot;Coup d'&#195;&#137;tat&quot;"` being a troublesome snippet.

I have used `html.unescape()` to successfully unescape most of the html codes, but I am struggling with the decoding of the special characters, `"&#195;&#137;"`, in this example. Ideally this would display as **"Coup d'État"**, but despite trying some decoding/encoding combinations I am getting "Coup d'Ãtat".

What is the correct way to convert `"&quot;Coup d'&#195;&#137;tat&quot;"` into `"Coup d'État"`?

Thanks for your help, and apologies if this has been answered elsewhere.  I've tried searching, but no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake), double-encoded data. You not only have HTML entities, your data was incorrectly decoded from bytes to text *before* the HTML entities were applied.

For your example, the two `&#195;`, `&#137;` entities decode to the Unicode characters `Ã` and `‰`. Those two characters are also known (from the Unicode standard), as `U+00C3 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH TILDE` and `U+2030 PER MILLE SIGN`. This is typical of UTF-8 data being mis-interpreted as a Latin variant encoding (such as [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) or a [Windows Latin codepage variant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#Windows-125x_series).

If we assume that the original character was meant to be `É`, or `U+00C9 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E WITH ACUTE`, then the original would have been encoded to the bytes `C3` and `89` if using UTF-8. That `Ã` (`U+00C3`!) shows up here is **not a coincidence**, it is typical of UTF-8 -> Latin variant Mojibakes to end up with such combinations. The `89` mapping tells us that the most likely candidate for the wrong encoding is the [Windows CP 1252 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which maps the hex value `89` to `U+2030 PER MILLE SIGN`.

You could manually encode to bytes then decode as the correct encoding, but the trick is to know *what encoding was used incorrectly*, and sometimes that mistake leads to data loss, because the CP-1252 codepage doesn't have a Unicode character mapping for 5 specific byte values. That's not a direct problem for the example in your question, but can be for other text. Manually decoding would work like this:

```
>>> import html
>>> broken = "&quot;Coup d'&#195;&#137;tat&quot;"
>>> html.unescape(broken)
'"Coup d\'Ã‰tat"'
>>> html.unescape(broken).encode("cp1252")
b'"Coup d\'\xc3\x89tat"'
>>> html.unescape(broken).encode("cp1252").decode("utf-8")
'"Coup d\'État"'
```

A better option is to use the special [`ftfy` library](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (the name is an acronym for *Fixed That For You*), which uses detailed knowledge about how to recognize such mistakes and undo the damage.

`ftfy` also handles the HTML-entity decoding, all in one step:

```
>>> import ftfy
>>> ftfy.fix_text("&quot;Coup d'&#195;&#137;tat&quot;")
'"Coup d\'État"'
```

The library includes [*sloppy* variants of text codes often found in a Mojibake](https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#module-ftfy.bad_codecs.sloppy) to help with repairing. It also encodes information about how to recognize the specific errors that a given wrong codec choice produces so it knows what to do to reverse the damage.